# How do I Upload & compile my .C code in the GDB?

Tags: virtual-machine, shared-directory, mounted-volumes

I have a very basic question, I installed Oracle VirtualBox, and I imported and run a virtual machine image (OVF file format) which contains a .C code example which I can compile and run without any problem.

See this print screens:

1. https://i.ibb.co/gmZds9B/Img1.jpg
2. https://i.ibb.co/gFzFbRK/Img2.jpg

But what if I want to upload and compile My Own .C code (for example: "myCode.c") from one of the folders in my computer?

I don't see any menu for opening or uploading a file from my PC.

Please advice,
Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, it seems that your question has nothing to do with C, Linux, compilation or GDB. It’s about how to copy files between a virtual machine disk image and the host filesystem. Is that correct?

Comment: I guess you want to setup [shared folders](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders)

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph It's a question about how to work with the GDB, I saw many questions here about this tool.

Comment: @Mathieu I will check this, thanks!